# How can Playwright test traffic be identified so it can be filtered from analytics?

Tags: analytics, playwright

I'm writing a suite of tests in Playwright. These tests will be run against multiple environments, including production. However, production has analytics and I'm concerned that running the suite on a regular basis could skew the numbers.

Is there any way to identify Playwright test traffic so that it can be filtered from the analytics reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I haven't worked much with Playwright, preferring Selenium and Puppeteer for this kind of automation, however, the way we do it there is typically by indicating the fact that this is a bot in the useragent. This snippet should work for Playwright pretty well:

```js
const {webkit} = require('playwright');
(async () => {
  const browser = await webkit.launch();
  // Create a new incognito browser context with a proper user agent
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    userAgent: 'Playwright Bot for internal QA automation'
  });
  // Now the page will have the user agent 
  const page = await context.newPage('https://example.com');
  console.log(await page.evaluate(() => navigator.userAgent));
})();
```

Took it from their [git repo issues](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/697). However, they have a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5935) there that they won't fix. But it looks like that's only when you're using proxies, which, I imagine, you won't. And even if you do, there's a workaround, so we should be good relying on the user agent.

It is good, however, to reach out to your analytics department and let them know that you're gonna send multiple hits to them through the testing, indicating how they can filter out your traffic. They may need time to create rules in their tag management systems to re-route your testing traffic tracking to the lower environment analytics database based on the user agent. Don't forget to tell them that the tests are planned to be run in prod though since it's a rare occasion and they should prepare.

Comment: Of course this is not a question directly related with Playwright itself, it is something can affect you with any other tool. The solution you gave looks really good to me, you can always talk with the analytics department to filter the requests done with your automation tool by user-agent

Comment: Worth noting, Playwright uses Puppeteer.

Answer (score 2):

## Filter *Internal* Traffic out by Client IP Address

If your testing environment is confined within a known and *stable* range of IP addresses you can [mark traffic coming from those as *internal*](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10104470?hl=en&ref_topic=9751244) and subsequently filter it out with the native GA4 [Internal traffic filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10108813#create).

*More thorough and complete explanation can be found [here](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/how-to-exclude-internal-traffic-in-google-analytics-4).*

## Use a Special Build with Disabled GA Code

Second option is to use a *feature flag* disabling GA/GTM initialization code when building application to be tested.

Not applicable here because question is about testing the already running production code, which can't use customized build by definition.
Won't get into details here.

## Pass Special Query Param in URLs You are Testing

Verbose but totally doable approach of adding something like `?ga_debug_mode=true` query param to product URLs you are testing.

Product code will have to pick that param up early on during it's bootstrapping process, and promptly disable the GA/GTM initialization code.

Has its caveats due to the cost of maintenance and issues with opening popups which might be unaware of the flag.
To my knowledge there is no dedicated Playwright config field which we could leverage to make it easier.

We can also use a completely custom (request) HTTP header and a cookie (to be set by server and then read by JS code) to let our application know that this is a testing client clicking through it.

We can use the [`network.extraHTTPHeaders` playwright config field](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#network) to add our custom request header, but server code would have to be changed for this to work.

## Use the `storageState.origins[].localStorage` to Disable Google Analytics

By configuring `storageState.origins[].localStorage` we can make sure that every browser instance spun up by Playwright has our custom `ga_debug_mode` flag set to `true` in its `localStorage`.

Then, again, product code has to read the flag and disable (skip) GTM/GA4 code when required. I.e.:

```html
<script>
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('ga_debug_mode') !== 'true') {
    // GTM or GTAG Initialization code
  }
</script>
```

Relevant part of Playwright config:

```js
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const storageState = {
  cookies: [], // not used but required by type definition
  origins: [{
    origin: '*', // doesn't narrow hostname at all. Use with caution!
    localStorage: [
      {
        name: 'ga_debug_mode', // feel free to modify the property name
        value: 'true', // this is a string
      },
    ],
  }],
};

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: 'https://example.com/',
    browserName: 'chromium',
    headless: true,
    storageState,
  },
};
```

## Further Reading

Besides skipping the initialization code, we can mark all GA events as *developer traffic* with `debug_mode: true` event parameter and filter those out later with the native GA Developer Traffic filter. Similar to the way how we can filter out *internal* traffic from GA reports.

There are differences in disabling (or marking events with `debug_mode`) GA script installed with GTAG script (older approach) and the one being initialized with the Google Tag Manager.

I do explore and describe all those options in depth here: [How to Exclude Playwright Test Traffic from Google Analytics](https://lab.amalitsky.com/posts/2022/exclude-playwright-test-traffic-from-google-analytics/#filter-developer-traffic-from-google-analytics-reports). Hope you will find it helpful.